# what is wrong in the getting json in swift 4?

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift4

I have a weather forecast JSON and I used new method in Swift 4 to serialize JSON with structure but the problem is that I will receive this when I want to print JSON:

> typeMismatch(Swift.Array, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Here is my codes for JSON:

```
struct currently : Decodable {
let summary : String?
let temperature : Float?
let timezone : String

init(json : [String : Any]) {

    summary = json["summary"] as? String ?? ""
    temperature = json["temperature"] as? Float ?? -1
    timezone = json["timezone"] as? String ?? ""



}
}
```

And here is the code for getting JSON:

```
let jsonURL =  "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/[code]/\(ViewController.latitude),\(ViewController.longitude)"

    guard let url = URL(string : jsonURL) else {
        return
    }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data , response , error) in

        guard let data = data else {return}

        do {


            let currentlies =  try JSONDecoder().decode(currently.self , from : data)


            print(currentlies.timezone)
            print(currentlies.summary)
            print(currentlies.temperature)

        }

        catch {

            print(error)
        }
    }.resume()
```

Comment: The error is clear. Your JSON root is a dictionary but you are treating it like an array.

Comment: so how can I use dictionary in swift 4 ?

Comment: " how can I use dictionary in swift 4" search that in google

Comment: that's good Idea :))) But please help me with writing the answer

Comment: Change your `currentlies` variable to a dictionary. Change the first parameter of your call to `decode` to a dictionary with the proper types.

Comment: I used that But I think I have done some thing wrong could you edit and and write new codes please?

Comment: Update your question with your attempt to use a dictionary and update whatever issues you are having.

Comment: Remove the square brackets on your decode line: `decode(currently.self , from : data!)`

Comment: ok I have edited my codes and the problem is that I can print time zone but the other ones are inside array and their print are nil

Comment: @SaeedRahmatolahi Why have you used `init` in your struct if you are using the `JSONDecoder()` as Swift 4 maps like an object mapper library itself. For the second part of your answer where there is an array, you can watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YY3bTxgxWss to understand how mapping works.

Comment: I have seen this movie but I couldn't understand the last minutes please write correct answer here and I will vote your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use like this :

```
struct Response : Decodable {
    let timezone : String
    let currently: Currently
}

struct Currently: Decodable {
    let summary: String
    let temperature: Double
}

let jsonURL =  "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/[code]/\(ViewController.latitude),\(ViewController.longitude)"

guard let url = URL(string : jsonURL) else {
    return
}

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data , response , error) in
   guard let data = data else {return}
    do {
        let currentlies =  try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self , from : data)

        print(currentlies.timezone)
        print(currentlies.currently.summary)
        print(currentlies.currently.temperature)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}.resume()
```

Comment: that's right this is What I wanted to know thanks a lot